# Getting SpeechRecognizer to correctly utilize timeouts for EndSilenceTimeout

Tags: c#, uwp, speech-recognition, session-timeout

I'm trying to re-purpose a code-snippet for a UWP app using `Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition`'s `SpeechRecognizer` class.

The problem is that it doesn't seem to utilize the timeout that I set for `EndSilenceTimeout` -- yet both `BabbleTimeout` and `InitialSilenceTimeout` appear to be working just fine. Basically, a 1-2 second pause will always end the session, and I'm trying to figure out how to fix or work around this.

I've tried with both `RecognizeAsync` and `RecognizeWithUIAsync` but neither made a difference.

```
private async void StartRecognizing()
{
    var speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer();

    speechRecognizer.Timeouts.EndSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    speechRecognizer.Timeouts.BabbleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    speechRecognizer.Timeouts.InitialSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

    await speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();

    SpeechRecognitionResult speechRecognitionResult = await speechRecognizer.RecognizeAsync();

    var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(speechRecognitionResult.Text, "Text spoken");
    await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

To test this, just make a new UWP app in Visual Studio and grant yourself permission to access the microphone in the package app manifest; additionally you'll need to make sure your OS itself allows for this in the *Speech, inking, & typing* settings on Windows 10 v1803.

Comment: hi @kayleeFrye_onDeck, this is know issue, and the related member fixing this, please pay attention to the latest update.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT could you please direct me to this information? I couldn't find anything when looking for known issues for `SpeechRecognizer`, and I'm already using `Windows 10, version 1803 (10.0; Build 17134)` as my Target Version.

Comment: This bug has been recorded, but the bug id is only visible internally.